# $\sum_{\hat{0}= x_0 < x_1 < \cdot \cdot \cdot < x_k = \hat{1}} (-1)^k \mu ([x_0, x_1 ]) \mu ([x_1, x_2 ]) \cdot \cdot \cdot \mu ([x_{k-1}, x_k ]) = 1$

Tags: combinatorics

Use incidence algebras to prove that

$\sum_{\hat{0}= x_0 < x_1 < \cdot \cdot \cdot < x_k = \hat{1}} (-1)^k \mu ([x_0, x_1 ]) \mu ([x_1, x_2 ]) \cdot \cdot \cdot \mu ([x_{k-1}, x_k ]) = 1$

> By definicion
>   $f\cdot g ([x,y]) = \sum_{x < z < y} f([x, z]) g([z, y ])$
>   Then
>   $\sum_{\hat{0}= x_0 < x_1 < \cdot \cdot \cdot < x_k = \hat{1}} (-1)^k \mu ([x_0, x_1 ]) \mu ([x_1, x_2 ]) \cdot \cdot \cdot \mu ([x_{k-1}, x_k ]) = \mu \mu \cdot \cdot \cdot \mu ([x_{0},x_k]) (-1)^k$
>   By definition of $\mu$

$\mu ^k (x)=  -1$  if it's on the top of the chain, 
or $\mu ^k (x)=  1$ otherwise

But I don't know if my definition of $\mu ^k (x)$ its true.

Comment: Can you fix the latex? There are some typos there. Also, is $k$ fixed? Are you working in a particular poset or is a general statement?

Comment: It's fixed, and is in general

Comment: This is not true for all posets, and all $k$. When $k=1$, this is just saying that $(-1)\mu([\hat 0,\hat 1])=1$. But this is not true for all posets. For example, any totally ordered set has $\mu([\hat 0,\hat 1])=0$. So, some assumptions are missing. What is $k$ defined as?